# The Two Water Jug Puzzle

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

I am trying to solve the two [WATER JUG PUZZLE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-water-jug-puzzle/) using euclidean algorithm and Diophantine equation.

1. let gcd(m,n) = g
2. using euclidean aldortihm we get X' and Y' such that mX' + nY' = g

for mX + nY = d

1. if d%g!= 0  no solution exists
2. else i made X' as X' / g * d and Y' as Y' / g * d

this is one solution for mX + nY = d

now multiple solutions by m ( X' + ( k * n / g ) ) + n ( Y' - ( m * k / g ) ) = d

i just needed to output the SUM OF  NO. OPERATIONS

so, i think of the solution as X' + Y' + k * ( n - m ) / g and i want to minimise this

my code below for the same (its giving wrong answers...)

```
   int X, Y;

   int gcd(int a, int b)
   {
       if (b == 0)
       {
           X = 1;
           Y = 0;
           return a;
       }
       int g = gcd(b, a % b);
       int X1 = Y;
       int Y1 = X - (a / b) * Y;
       X = X1;
       Y = Y1;
       return g;
   }



    cin >> m >> n >> d;
    int g = gcd(n, m);
    if (d % g)
        cout << -1 << endl;
    else
    {
        X = X / g * d;
        Y = Y / g * d;
        int ans = X + Y;
        int mn = ans;
        while (ans > 0)
        {
            ans += ((m - n) / g);
            mn = min(ans, mn);
        }
        while (ans < 10000)
        {
            ans += ((n - m) / g);
            mn = min(ans, mn);
        }
        cout << mn << endl;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what language?

Comment: Have you read [ask]?

Comment: @Enigmativity please refer to the WATER JUG PUZZLE its a pretty standard problem and also I HAVE MADE IT A HYPERLINK.

Comment: click on water jug puzzle

Comment: Thanks, but what are you asking us? Please also read [ask].